# Trigger Modal in Angular 5 on Form Submission

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I'm working with Angular 5 and Bootstrap 3. One of my forms is emailing the content of the input fields and also contains a modal. I would like to trigger the modal on successful or error response from the server.
I was trying to trigger with *ngIf but it doesn't work. Here is the part of HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div>
      <input></input> 
    </div>
  </form>

<div *ngIf="emailSuccess" #modalInfo class="modal fade" id="modal">
modal body
</div>
```

And here is part of my .ts flie:

```
sendEmail(data) {
    this.appService.sendEmail(data.myForm.value).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
      if (data.success) {
        this.emailSuccess = true;
        this.messageHeader = 'Thank You';
        this.messageBody = 'We received your email';
        this.myForm.reset();
      } else if (data.error) {
        this.emailSuccess = false;
        this.messageHeader = 'Error';
        this.messageBody = 'Something went wrong. Please, check your form and try again';
      }
    });
  }
```

sendEmail() is trriger on:

```
<button type="button" (click)="sendEmail(this)" class="btn btn-primary " [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to display modal no matter if send was successful or error with a proper message. Therefore, the solution to my problem was to hook up a modal trigger to **Submit** button.

Code before:

```
<button type="button" (click)="sendEmail(this)" class="btn btn-primary " [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

Edited code:

```
<button type="button" (click)="sendEmail(this)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal" [disabled]="!maintenanceForm.valid">Submit</button>
```